# C# Serverside form validation and rerender

Tags: c#, forms, validation, view, render

I'd like to be able to validate forms server-side (maybe check the database for duplicate entries for a registration form) in addition to client side. I've written my validation logic, but I'd like to rerender the view and have the form values the user submitted to be available. Also, I'd like to place an error message and maybe change the color of the font or add an X where a field was invalid. Basically I'm looking to do the equivalent of what formencode and htmlfill does in Python. What would be the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: We need more specifics to handle the question, however, with the use of field validators as well as simple if / else logic you could accomplish just this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ASP.NET, the easiest way would be using a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control where you can place your own logic in the validator. A lot of the validation you could probably accomplish with the built-in validator controls like RequiredFieldValidator and CompareValidator.

Comment: Do my form and form fields in the aspx pages need to be asp controls instead of html?

Comment: @jchysk Typically you would check it on Postback, but you can wire up Text_Changed events or whatever to validate if you need to. You can set a CustomValidator to work off nothing, so it doesn't necessarily have to work off an asp.net control, but if you want the benefit of saving the values on postback through viewstate, then they controls need to be set to runat="server". You can wire up a Client side event to the validator to do a check there. In that case, you'd probably have to wire up some script to check a webmethod or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have a copule of options:

(1) Using ASP.NET you can do a Postback and perform your validation, etc. on the server-side.

(2) Using Ajax with a Javascript library such as jQuery or Prototype you can accomplish the same thing with a cleaner user experience.